# Integer printing as Alt Code

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a C++ Linked List and running into some very interesting behavior.

```
string LinkedList::toString() {
    string output = "";
    Node *cur = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        output += "node ";
        output += i;
        output += ": ";
        output += cur->toString();
        output += "\n";
        cur = cur->getNext();
    }
    return output;
}
```

The above code all runs correctly, except for one little exception...

[image]

The `i` in my for-loop is being printed as an [alt-code](http://www.alt-codes.net/)! Why??

Comment: it is taking it as ascii value use `itoa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put a number (i.e., `i`) into a string without converting it to characters first. The result is that the string contains a character with that numeric code. Given how most common character sets are laid out, a character with a code less than 32 is typically going to be a control code.

You probably want to use `std::to_string` to convert the number to a string before adding it to the existing string. Alternatively, format the data into a `stringstream`, then return its content, something on this general order:

```
string LinkedList::toString() {
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    Node *cur = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        buffer << "node " << i << ": " << cur->toString() << "\n";
        cur = cur->getNext();
    }
    return buffer.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is treating `i` as a char & taking its ASCII value.

Comment: How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `int`s to your `output` `string`. These are being displayed as their ASCII representation.

You can fix this using [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) (untested):

```
std::string LinkedList::toString() {
    std::ostringstream output;
    Node *cur = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        output << "node ";
        output << i;
        output << ": ";
        output << cur->toString();
        output << "\n";
        cur = cur->getNext();
    }
    return output.str();
}
```

This may be more readable as:

```
std::string LinkedList::toString() {
    std::ostringstream output;
    Node *cur = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        output << "node " << i << ": " cur->toString() << "\n";
        cur = cur->getNext();
    }
    return output.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itoa` for changing int to ascii. simply solves your problem.
Try Following code:

```
 string LinkedList::toString() {
string output = "";
char buff[100];
Node *cur = first;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    itoa(i,buff,10);
    output += "node ";
    output += buff;
    output += ": ";
    output += cur->toString();
    output += "\n";
    cur = cur->getNext();
}
return output;
}
```